using SparkTrials to parallelise hyperopt parameter run
I am trying to hyperparameter tune my Keras Autoencoder using the hyperopt library and log the results in MLFlow. This is what my AutoEncoder class looks like :
class AutoEncoder(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def __init__(
        self,
        kernel_initializer,
        num_layers,
        num_neurons,
        activation,
        regularization,
        reg_lambda,
    ):
        
        self.autoencoder = get_model(
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            num_layers=num_layers,
            num_neurons=num_neurons,
            activation=activation,
            regularization=regularization,
            reg_lambda=reg_lambda,
        )

    def load_context(self, context: None):
        pass

    def compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics):
        if self.autoencoder is None:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)


    def fit(self, X, y, epochs=None, batch_size=None, validation_data=None):

        history = self.autoencoder.fit(
            X,
            y,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            validation_data=validation_data,
            verbose=0,
        )
        return history

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        return self.autoencoder.predict(model_input)

And this is my objective function:-
def objective(params):
    
    learning_rate = params["learning_rate"]
    optimizer = params["optimizer"]
    kernel_initializer = params["kernel_initializer"]
    num_layers = int(params["num_layers"])
    num_neurons = int(params["num_neurons"])
    activation = params["activation"]
    regularization = params["regularization"]
    reg_lambda = params["lambda"]
    autoencoder = AutoEncoder(
        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
        num_layers=num_layers,
        num_neurons=num_neurons,
        activation=activation,
        regularization=regularization,
        reg_lambda=reg_lambda,
    )
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])    

    # Train the Autoencoder model
    history = autoencoder.fit(
        X_train,
        X_train,
        batch_size=32,
        epochs=1,
        validation_data=(X_val, X_val),
    )
    with mlflow.start_run(nested=True):
        mlflow.log_params(params)
        # mlflow.log_model("autoencoder_model",python_model=autoencoder)
        mlflow.log_metric("val_loss", history.history["val_loss"][-1])

  return history.history["val_loss"][-1]

When I try running the hyperparameter tuning job using hyperopt.Trials(), I am able to see results logged in MlFlow, but if I replace the hyperopt.Trials() with hyperopt.SparkTrials(), I get the following error :-
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 189, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 541, in loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/exceptions.py", line 117, in __init__
    error_code = json.get("error_code", ErrorCode.Name(INTERNAL_ERROR))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' 

How can I fix this issue? I am assuming the challenge is with how Spark is parallelising the objective function, given that everything works as expected with Trials(). Any help in fixing this will be appreciated.
